# Swift import local file import into SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift

I have to share the same data among 6 different apps so I thought a JSON file was the best way to save the data on each app.

I created a local file called "AppsInfo.json".

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "app1",
        "desc": "",
        "amount": "19.99",
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "app2",
        "desc": "",
        "amount": "14.99",
        }
}
```

I can get the file path with this:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AppsInfo", ofType: "json");
```

Now how do I load this file into something like SwiftyJSON?

Using Swift 4.2.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you going to access the main bundle of one app from other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you read the `Data` from the path, better return `URL` of the resource

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppsInfo", withExtension: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
        let json = JSON(data: data)
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I keep getting an error `invalid filename/path`. I've tried putting the file in the project directory and in the `Assets.xassets` directory in an attempt to link to it but neither works. What could be wrong?