# Cannot link to local file with SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, xcode, swifty-json

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863489/swift-import-local-file-import-into-swiftyjson), but the solution isn't working for me. I added `devotions.json` to my project folder (I also tried in the assets directory, as you seen in the example below). I keep getting the else statement error `Invalid filename/path`.

You can see here that both instances of the JSON file should be accessible:
[image]

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "assets/devotions", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            let jsonObj = try JSON(data: data)
            print("jsonData:\(jsonObj)")
        } catch let error {
            print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
```

Is this a simple syntax error? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was even though I had added it the json file through the finder window Xcode didn't recognize it until I dragged the json file directly into Xcode's project navigator, then it was able to access it.